# Trying to change last to "x"s to 23

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been playing around with `IRB` and have a string that looks like this:

```
irb(main):072:0> puts a
["[\"4354 5432 5432 xxxxx\", \"6547 6547 8543 xxxxx\", \"2344 6543 6674 xxxxx\", \"2346 6236 7543 xxxxx\", \"1273 5585 5587 xxxxx\"]"]
=> nil
irb(main):073:0>
```

What I want to do is `gsub` the last two `"x"`s of each *17 digit* combination, with `23`.

What I've tried to far (I've been using Rubular):

- `a.gsub(/\D[x]/,"23")` <= Grabs all the `"x"`s so I'm close
- `a.gsub(/\w[x{2}]/,"23")` <= Grabs all the `"x"`s but also grabs *two
  digits* from each combination.

Is there an easier way to do this that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Do you mean [`xx\b` -> `23`](https://regex101.com/r/rF2sH4/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev That could work lol

Comment: Look, ndn has a more specific solution, mine is rather broad. Mine will match any 2 `x` characters that are followed by a non-word character or end of string.

Comment: Some suggestions for improving the question: 1. It appears that `a` is an array containing a single string. If so, refer to the string directly (e.g., `str = "[\"43...")`. 2. Drop the reference to IRB and the IRB prompts. Writing it as in #1 allows readers to cut and paste. 3. Reduce the length of the string to the minimum needed to make your point (say 2 or 3 groups, which could be read without the need for horizontal scrolling). 4. Show the string that is the desired result for your example. 5. Your reference to "17 digits" is confusing. Do you want to replace "xxxxx" with 23"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Does that look better?

Comment: Actually you've changed an array of one string to an array of several strings that are missing some characters you had previously. You have in fact changed the question, a no-no for very good reasons. Best to go to edit history and roll-back to your original question. Just consider my original comment as suggestions for the future.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes stackoverlord... Why even bother if when I change it you're going to whine about it?

Comment: I was just trying to offer some general advice, mainly for questions you may post in future. I didn't expect you were going to change the question. If you puruse some of the questions posted by veteran SO members, you will see that they all have the characteristics I was advocating. It is also consistent with advice posted at the [SO Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.gsub(/\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} xxx\Kxx/, '23')
```

`\d{4}` = 4 digits

What [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) does is drop what was matched so far. You can use it so that you don't replace the entire number, but still be able to validate you have it in the desired format.

Comment: Why do you grab digits three times, before grabbing the characters?

Comment: @Bam, because I wanted to verify it's in the format that you showed. For example, stribizhev's answer will replace the `xx`ses in `foo xx` too. If you are sure there won't be any such scenario, you can use a simpler answer. A matter protecting againsts false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Though @ndn’s solution is pretty fine, here is another approach. The string looks very similar to json, so:

```
input = "[\"4354 5432 5432 xxxxx\", \"6547 6547 8543 xxxxx\"]"

require 'json'
JSON.parse(input).map { |e| e.sub /xx\z/, '23' }.to_json
#⇒ "[\"4354 5432 5432 xxx23\", \"6547 6547 8543 xxx23\"]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to replace any two `xx` that are at the end of a "word", you may use a

```
a.gsub(/xx\b/, '23') 
# => ["4354 5432 5432 xxx23", "6547 6547 8543 xxx23"]
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ddk0jE) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF2sH4/1)

`/xx\b/` matches any 2 `x` characters that are followed by a non-word character or end of string.

Comment: Yeah, this one was already brought to my attention as a comment above, it's super short, but a little broad

Comment: :) Just as an option. Surely there might be super cool ways of doing it with Ruby magic, like the one shown by mudasobwa.